# Change variable of a class from another

Tags: python

I am trying to change a variable in one class from another without inheritance.

How could I do it?

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.modifier = _ClassB()
        self.var_a = 5


class _ClassB:
    def change_var_a(self):
        # change var_a = 7

a = ClassA()
a.modifier.change_var_a()
print(a.var_a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a reference to the instance to be modified:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.modifier = _ClassB(parent=self)
        self.var_a = 5


class _ClassB:
    def __init__(self, parent: ClassA):
        self.parent = parent

    def change_var_a(self):
        self.parent.var_a = 10


a = ClassA()
a.modifier.change_var_a()
print(a.var_a)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!